# django-redactor: addButtons

Tags: python, django, redactor

I'm trying to add button to redactor-editor by following way

```
redactor_options = {
        'lang' : 'en',
        'placeholder' : 'here',
        'buttonsAdd' : ['code_editor'],
        'buttonsCustom' : {
            'code_editor' : {
                'title' : 'CodeEditor',
                'callback' : "function(obj1, obj2, obj3){var a=1;}",
            }
        },
    },
```

but whenever i click button I got error msg in console
"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callback' of object # is not a function "

Comment: This sounds more as js issue, is your function defined inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` declaration? if yes then you move the function outside of it.

Comment: no, callback function needs to b written there only. I have written above code in views.py, nothing else

Comment: Remove the quotes from the callback function:
`callback: function(obj1, obj2, obj3){var a=1;}`

Comment: i said i'm writting this whole thing. in views.py, its not javacript. Have a look at this http://pastebin.mozilla.org/4060498

Comment: Sorry did not see the views.py comment (should add it in the original question), anyways I believe this can't work as you are trying to evaluate a string as a function, I believe you could make this work if you move the js declaration outside of your views.py, it should be ok if you add it into the template.

Comment: so in callback i should write the name of the function only i.e.
'callback':'functionName()'